# There is always a zero at the end of my algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic, algpseudocode

There is my source code.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}  
\usepackage[algcompatible]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!b]  
    \caption{algorithm 1}  
    \label{alg}  
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require  
        INFORMATION
        \Ensure  
        Model;
        \STATE CALCULATE
        \STATE END
        \RETURN MODEL
    \end{algorithmic}  
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it looks like this. No matter what I modified the content, the zero is always there.

[image]

Comment: Yes. And I know the problem is `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` which are not compatible. But I still have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Commenting on the package \usepackage{algorithmic} worked for me. Use just the packages: \usepackage{algorithm} and \usepackage{algpseudocode}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `algorithm2e` package

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetKwInput{Require}{Require}
\SetKwInput{Ensure}{Ensure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[!b]
    \caption{algorithm 1}
    \label{alg}
        \SetAlgoLined
        \Require{INFORMATION}
        \Ensure{MODEL}
        CALCULATE\\
        END\\
        \Return MODEL
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well, but what if I wanna use `\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}} 
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}} ` ? It doesn't work.

Comment: It's normal, since commands starting with `\algorithmic` are defined by the `algorithmic` package. Have a look at the package documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) Section 11, p32 to see how to define your own keywords, as well as already defined commands

Comment: I means that your solution is not compatible with the `\Require` and the `\Ensure`. Actually it works in my source code, but your solution skips it.

Comment: As I said, everything is in the documentation. I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry it was totally my fault. Thank you very much!